# Firebug Events side panel is empty

Tags: firefox, firebug

Did anyone ever notice that the *Events* side panel within the *HTML* panel in Firebug is not working anymore?

I'm used to relying on that functionality. Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It broke in Firefox 38, and will be fixed with the next new Firebug update. See [this newsgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/-lPQcqfiVYg).

Comment: Cool. How do apply the patch though?

Comment: Either apply it manually to the contents of `$mozillaprofile/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi` (which is a zip file containing the Firebug source; if you don't know how to find the profile directory, search for it), or go through the proceduces stated on https://github.com/firebug/firebug/ with the patch applied through git, or just use the XPI from the newsgroup thread.